# Is it possible to navigate to pivot control page by a button clicked event

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, pivot

I'm trying to create a wp7 pivot control application. On click of a button in the first page, I would like to navigate to another page which is already a pivot page. Is it possible ?

Comment: I'm sorry I din get you right. For navigating to the next page, we generally use : 
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SettingsPivot.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
However, In case of a Pivot application we have all the details in the same MainPage.xaml. So in that case, how should I navigate?

Comment: I'd seriously reconsider adding your own mechanic to change between the selected PivotItem. I've yet to see an app that does this well and which wouldn't be better off by having more pages and navigating between them in a more traditional manner.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you have for example following definition for the Pivot control:

```
 <controls:Pivot x:Name="SettingsPivot" Title="settings">
   <controls:PivotItem x:Name="GeneralSettings" Header="general settings">
     <!-- Pivot Item content -->
   </controls:PivotItem>
   <controls:PivotItem x:Name="ConnectivitySettings" Header="connectivity settings">
     <!-- Pivot Item content -->
   </controls:PivotItem>
   <controls:PivotItem x:Name="OtherSettings" Header="other settings">
     <!-- Pivot Item content -->
   </controls:PivotItem>
 </controls:Pivot>
```

Then you can go to for example OtherSettings using this code in the button click event handler:

```
SettingsPivot.SelectedItem = OtherSettings;
```

Comment: @New developer: Please consider accepting this as an answer if it was what you were after, so that this question gets closed in a proper way.

Comment: this kind of answers are like gold. I have been searching in MSDN, IRC channel, and google and lost my time to finally arrive to this one : great ! (+1)

Comment: Good one, but what if the button is in a page in one of the pivot items, how can I navigate to a different pivot from within the page? I'm in UWP developing now.

Answer (score 6):

do it like this

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Pages/Page.xaml?PivotMain.SelectedIndex = 0", UriKind.Relative));
```

SelectedIndex can be whatever depending how many pivot items you have

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can navigate to another page, it does not matter if it is a pivot page or not:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SettingsPivot.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

If you are trying to navigate to another *pivotitem* then you will need to do the following

```
int i=1; //This is the index of the pivotitem you would like to navigate to

PivotMenuName.SelectedIndex = i;
```

Comment: I'm sorry I din get you right. For navigating to the next page, we generally use : 
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SettingsPivot.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
However, In case of a Pivot application we have all the details in the same MainPage.xaml. So in that case, how should I navigate?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want the second piece of code. If your Pivot has 2 items, (say item1, item2), then to navigate to item2 from item1, you would use:

```
MyPivot.SelectedIndex = IndexOfPageToGoTo;
```

Check out this quick example that demonstrates it .

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/129101/WindowsPhonePivotApplication1.zip

That said, this isn't recommended if you're using it for a "Wizard" style application. See http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/08/13/windows-phone-panorama-versus-pivot-ux-guidelines.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("MainPage.xaml?PivotMain.SelectedIndex = 0", UriKind.Relative));
```

index goes 0-1-2-3 ... write which one you want to navigate.

Answer (score 0):

If you have dynamically create pivot items, you can use this easy code:

```
// This find object named as customName
object pvtItm = pivotName.FindName("customName");

// If this object has type of PivotItem, navigate to it
if (pvtItm is PivotItem)
{
    pivotName.SelectedItem = pvtItm;
}
```