# Create two side by side pages for Windows Phone development

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and can easily create a single page application. I would like to create a second page and have it appear to the right of the main page. Windows Phones will give you a little peek into the next page and you can swipe the screen to switch pages. How can this be done? I think it needs to be more than handling an event, because of the peek/preview we can see on the right edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Panorama Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941104%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) in WP8 SDK for this. Start with the `Windows Phone Panorama App` template in `Create New Project` in VS: [How to create a Panorama Windows Phone App](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941109%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Are you thinking of a [panorama control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202912%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)? This sounds like what you're talking about, although another option in most situations is a [pivot control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941098%28v=VS.92%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. I am just starting out and need a bit of guidance down the proper path.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see a a part of the next page you need to use [Panorama control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202912%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The **PIVOT CONTROL** is more manageable than the **PANORAMA**.

Panorama cannot navigate `programmatically` from one page to another, while the pivot control allows you that! [*see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176888/) for implementation*]

See [pivot control example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941103%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and compare with [panorama example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941109%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) if you will.

Comment: Thanks. Both controls are of interest to me.